# Different machine keys for different web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, web-config, machinekey

I have two web applications running under .NET4. Both the web applications are hosted on same server. I have two questions here:

Will both of these applications share same machine key? How can I have different machine keys for different applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are different applications, the default settings will give them a different machineKey. That's what [`IsolateApps`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9.aspx) is for.

> AutoGenerate, IsolateApps   Specifies that the key is automatically generated. This is the default value.

And IsolateApps means...

> The IsolateApps modifier specifies that ASP.NET generates a unique encrypted key for each application using the application ID of each application.

Comment: Can you let me know from where I can know they are isolated apps?

Comment: @RockySingh It's the default. Unless a web.config explicitly changes it to something else, that'll be what it is.

Comment: This means in .NET 4 each web application will have a separate machine key for it. Is this correct?

Comment: @RockySingh Yes. Take a look at the linked documentation.